# Using boto3's iter_lines to load a CSV with newlines in the data

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, memory, boto3

I am trying to load a single column of data out of a large CSV file from S3 with [boto3's `iter_lines()` function](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.iter_lines), but some of the CSV data contains newlines, so the data is getting mangled (example below).  I'm already using `csv.reader` to parse each line and yield/return the single column that I'm looking for, but that doesn't solve the problem if the line itself is wrong.  What's the best way to load the column data without loading the whole file into memory?

For example, if this is the raw content of "sample.csv":

```
"1","some regular content","12.34"
"2","some content\nwith a newline","56.78"
"3","some more regular content","9.001"
```

Then `[line for line in client.get_object(Bucket="my-bucket", key="sample.csv")["Body"].iter_lines()]` evaluates to:

```
[
    '"1","some regular content","12.34"',
    '"2","some content',
    'with a newline","56.78"',
    '"3","some more regular content","9.001"',
]
```

Here is the source of `iter_lines()`, if that gives anyone any inspiration: https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/49bbfb3f80a0b00275a57a9575a158aa22562552/botocore/response.py#L135

Comment: Would something like `csv.reader(....iter_lines())` do what you're after?

Comment: Use the CSV Reader library. It knows how to interpret CSV files. See: [csv — CSV File Reading and Writing — Python 3.11.0 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). You _might_ need to download the file first.

Comment: Good clarifications.  I updated the question.